# Server not visible in client

Tags: postgresql

I'm  trying to add a server in pgAdmin 3 to get started, but somehow server is not added. I fill all the fields as described [here](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/connect.html) but after OK button is pressed client writes in the bottom left corner "Connecting to database.... Done." and that's it. I presume it's quite trivial, but can't figure out what's wrong. Please, help.

NOTE: Using win xp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sure after you see the done text there is no server group name in the Object Browser?

Normally after you see the done message click on the server name in the object browser. You named this when you created your connection.  Once you click it, it will open up a tree view of objects for you to explore.

Comment: Might actually have to double click it.

Comment: Actually, UI bugged a bit, cause after app restart it showed all that was required.